# Why MySQL doesn't utilize leftmost Index field (UK - col1, col2, col3) in select query?

Tags: mysql, index, unique-constraint

I have a department table with the following structure

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,  -- Possible values are 0,1,2 only
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_2xsp2nild3xbgkg4pln7cviib` (`status`,`type`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Following query doesn't utilise the `status` index as it is the left most column in unique constraint.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM department d WHERE d.status = 1;

    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys                 key     key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra        
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  ----------------------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  --------  -------------
     1  SIMPLE       d       (NULL)      ALL     UK_2xsp2nild3xbgkg4pln7cviib  (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)       4    100.00  Using where
```

But when querying on another table which has unique constraint on a single column, it uses the index.

```
CREATE TABLE `account_unit` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `unit_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_2x8b55sxftahu8cjbqld9sw9b` (`unit_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM account_unit au WHERE au.`unit_name` = 'AU1'

    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys                 key                           key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra   
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  ----------------------------  ----------------------------  -------  ------  ------  --------  --------
     1  SIMPLE       au      (NULL)      const   UK_2x8b55sxftahu8cjbqld9sw9b  UK_2x8b55sxftahu8cjbqld9sw9b  767      const        1    100.00  (NULL)
```

As per my understanding, left most column on a multi column constraint will be utilized  as index on select queries. Enlighten me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the status column?

Comment: And what % of the rows in the table have status=1?

Comment: @AndrewBrennan, Most likely everything will be 1, very very few 0, no 2

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, currently < 100

Comment: Then the optimiser is right to skip the index. A full table scan is more efficient.

Comment: You should mark G-Nugget's answer as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certainly due to the low cardinality of the index on the first column.  Since there are only 3 values, the optimizer decides that it is better do do a full scan on the table.

Using the index on the first column will point to about one third of the rows.  Looking up that many rows based on the primary key will likely lead to practically all of the primary key pages being pulled into the buffer along with a large portion of the secondary index pages, leading to more memory usage and potentially disk traffic.  Overall, it is more efficient and usually about the same speed to just do a full scan on the data if a large portion of the data is likely to be selected based on a secondary index lookup.